# Laravel 4 - Blade Templating - How to properly Link to Route?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I want to create a resourceful link with Laravel. 
Normally I just use the `{{ link_to_route('Yadayadayada.route', 'LinkName', $params }}`

But in this case I am using a Template with this layout:

```
<a href="index.html">
     <i class="icon-dashboard"></i>
     <span class="menu-text"> Dashboard </span>
</a>
```

That means that inside the anchor tag, is as well a `<i>`-Tag and a `<span>`-Tag.
Is it possible to use the `{{ link_to_route }}`-Method, without having to change the layout of the Template?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `URL::route()` to get just a link:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('user/profile/', $params) }}">
     <i class="icon-dashboard"></i>
     <span class="menu-text"> Dashboard </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for an astoundingly quick answer.

Comment: How can I make the same technique for destroy function??
I tried 

    href="{{ route('shops.destroy', $row->id ) }}"  data-method="delete" 
but I redirects me to show() instead!!!!

Comment: @Dr.MAF - `href="{{ route('shops.destroy', $row->id).'?_method=delete' }}"`

Comment: @Dr.MAF you must include the javascript file `rails.js` from the https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs project (if you want to maintain it from laravel, use https://github.com/efficiently/jquery-laravel ).
Then use what you wrote in your comment.

Answer (score 17):

If you Route use a Closure, you can use `URL::to()`, like this

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('home/otherpage', $params) }}">
    <i class="icon-dashboard"></i>
    <span class="menu-text"> Dashboard </span>
</a>
```

As @orrd sugested, in general terms is better to use named routes, so it can be easily change the URL later:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('routeName', $params) }}">
    <i class="icon-dashboard"></i>
    <span class="menu-text"> Dashboard </span>
</a>
```

(ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#urls)

Comment: It's better to use named routes whenever possible rather than repeating the URL multiple places in your code (so you can easily change the URL later in one place if you needed to).

Comment: @orrd thats right, i've updated the response with you sugestion

Answer (score 5):

if you define Route name you can use that in your blade :

```
 Route::get('/admin/transfer/forms-list', [
    'as'   => 'transfer.formsList',
    'uses' => 'Website\TransferController@IndexTransferForms'
]);
```

now you can use that in your blade like this :

```
<a href="{{URL::route('transfer.formsList')}}"  type="submit">
                    discard</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

There are no of ways to use route in blade:

**1. Use Action**

```
{{URL::action('DemoController@index',$params)}}
```

**2. Use Route**

```
{{ URL::route('route/', $params) }}
```

**3. Use URL to**

```
{{ URL::to('route/name', $params) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use URL::route() to get just a link:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('user/profile/', $params) }}">
     <i class="icon-dashboard"></i>
     <span class="menu-text"> Dashboard </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

{{ link_to_route('dashboard', 'Dashboard', '', array('class'=>'body')) }}