# Laravel multiple route aliases

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I'm trying to **create a route with an array of aliases**, so when I call `whois` or `who_is` in the url it goes to the same route.

Then I don't need to keep repeating the code every time, changing only the alias.

I tried the code below.

***Variables in the routes:***

```
$path = 'App\Modules\Content\Controllers\ContentController@';
$aliases['whois'] = '(quemsomos|who_is|whois)';
```

***Routes:***

```
Route::get('{whois}', array('as' =>'whois', 'uses' => $path.'getWhois'))->where('whois', $aliases['whois']);
```

this one works as well

```
Route::get('{whois}', $path.'getWhois')->where('whois', $aliases['whois']);
```

Typing in the url `my_laravel.com/whois` or `my_laravel.com/who_is` or `my_laravel.com/quemsomos` will send me to `$path.'getWhois'` *(which is correct)*.

But when I try to call it in the html on blade...

```
<a href="{{ route('whois') }}">Who we are</a>
```

The reference link goes to `my_laravel.com//%7Bwhois%7D`

How could I call `route('whois')` on my blade.php and make it work like when I type it on the url ?

I would like to use the `route` function` in my blade, so I can keep a pattern.

Comment: would like help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751866/laravel-4-blade-templating-how-to-properly-link-to-route?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

During route generation using the `route` function, Laravel expects you to set the value of the route parameter. You are leaving the parameter whois empty so the parameter capturing `{whois}` will not be replaced and results in the `%7B` and `&7D` for the accolades.

So in order to generate a route you will need to define what value you'd like to use for whois; `{{ route('whois', ['whois'=>'whois']) }}` for instance.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot for the explanation on how `route` function works! It worked like a charme. Thanks :)