# Laravel href redirection

Tags: laravel

So I've started using Laravel and I found it very easy and now I'm creating my own restful services. My problem is I don't know if I am doing the href link correct, but yes it is working. Here is the code:

```
<a href="{{URL::to('accounts/create')}}">Add user</a>
```

And in my controller I just render the blade:

```
public function create()
{
    return view('accounts.create');
}
```

So if I click the link Add user, it will redirect me to `localhost:8080/accounts/create` which is working well. My question is, is there a better way of doing this? Like if ever I changed any in my routes file, I will not change anymore the href link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 - Blade Templating - How to properly Link to Route?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751866/laravel-4-blade-templating-how-to-properly-link-to-route)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you will name the route in your routes file.
Something like,

```
Route::get('accounts/create', [as => 'createAccount', 'uses' => 'AccountsController@create']);
```

You will use it as follows

```
<a href="{{URL::route('createAccount')}}">Add user</a>
```

in your view.

This way, even if you change the url (accounts/create), or the action name (create), you will not have to change it in the view. Allows your view to be independent.

Comment: Thank you for this sir, can I ask a question? Do I really need to do "laravel new app_name" always in every app that I do?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is give your route a name using the `as` key in the array in the second argument of your route:

```
Route::get('accounts/create', [
    'as'   => 'accounts.create',
    'uses' => 'AccountController@create'
]);
```

Then you can refer to this route in your application by it's name and it'll go to the same place even if you happen to change the URL. For an anchor tag you can do the following:

```
{{ URL::route('accounts.create') }}
```

If you're using a resource controller there will be predefined routes which you can see here under **Actions Handled By Resource Controller**: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

You can always get a quick overview of your available routes and their names by running `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Thank you for this sir, can I ask a question? Do I really need to do "laravel new app_name" always in every app that I do?

Comment: You're welcome, thank you for thanking me. As for your question, you're talking about using the laravel installer to create a new project, right? If so, yes you do, but fyi comments aren't really the place to ask a separate question. Try to create a new question here or try asking in one of laravels communities such as laravel.io forums laracasts.com forums or laravel irc if you have further questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes

Example:

```
Route::get('accounts/create', array('as' => 'signup', 'uses' => 'UserController@create'));

<a href="{{URL::route('signup')}}">Add user</a>
```

This route is named as "signup" and you can change the url anytime as:

```
Route::get('accounts/signup', array('as' => 'signup', 'uses' => 'UserController@create'));
```

Comment: Thank you for this sir, can I ask a question? Do I really need to do "laravel new app_name" always in every app that I do?

Comment: There are other ways also to setup Laravel as:
`composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`
But you should always use one of these to setup everytime.
Or just copy fresh Laravel copy into another project and composer install.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the action() helper to call a method inside a controller and generate the route to it automatically on demand.

So let's consider you have a controller called FrontendController.php and a method called showFrontend( $section), and assuming that you have a route that matches this controller and method (let's say "frontend/show/{$section}", you can call:

```
action('FrontendController@showFrontend', array( 'index' ) )
```

That will return:

```
frontend/show/index
```

So basically it looks for the route associated to that method/controller. You can combine this with other helpers to create a whole URL.

NOTE: Consider the namespaces, in case that you have different folder for controllers, nested resources, etc.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for this sir, can I ask a question? Do I really need to do "laravel new app_name" always in every app that I do?

Comment: That command is just to create a fresh installation of the Laravel package. You can either use that command to create a new project based on laravel, or you can use composer, or you can just download the code from Github and place it wherever you want, etc... You can find more information here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1